# Using jQuery to fetch variable from my database

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have done some reading and I think i need to use json for this. I have never used this before. I am trying to accomplish this, but in jQuery

```
$email_exist_check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email='$desired_email'") or die(mysql_error());
$email_exist = mysqli_num_rows($email_exist_check);
    if ($email_exist == 0) {
//stop and make user write something else
} else {
//keep going

}
```

I am switching my website over from php to jQuery, which is also very new to me but seems so much better. Here is a piece of my jQuery. I am validating a form. The form works and submits, but now i want to see if the email exists in my database before submission. How would i do this?

```
 if (email == "") {
    $("#error5").css("display", "inline");
    $("#email").focus();
    return false;
  }

// Im guessing the new code would go here

  var dataString = $("#acc_form").serialize();
var action = $("#acc_form").attr('action');

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: action,
   data: dataString,
   success: window.location.assign("cashcheck_order.php")

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic ajax call using jquery

```
var thing1; //thing 1 to use in js
var thing2; //thing 2 to use
var form = ("#acc_form"); //localize the form to a variable. you don't need to keep looking it up
var dataString = form.serialize();
var action = form.attr('action');

$.ajax({
    url: action,
    data: dataString,
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){
        var responseData = $.parseJSON(data); //json native decoding if available, otherwise will do it with jquery
        thing1 = responseData["thing1"];
        thing2 = responseData["thing2"];
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("error", data);
    }
});
```

On the php side, to bring the vars in you use

```
$input1 = isset($_GET["name_of_input1"]) ? $_GET["name_of_input1"] : "";
```

if this is set, set this value, else set blank. 
you can use $_POST, $_REQUEST if you prefer.
do not forget to sanitize your inputs.

Now to send it back to the js file

```
$dataToReturn = [
"thing1"=>"I'm thing 1",
"thing2"=>"I'm thing 2"
];

//sending back data

echo json_encode($dataToReturn);
```